# Automatic deletion of old files FTP User folder Ubuntu Server

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-12.04

Right now i currently have a FTP server up and running on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS 64-bit with Proftpd.

I have it limiting each of the users for the FTP to a certain size depending on the user and their data storage capacity.

However, for the ones that are uploading video to the FTP server i need to automatically delete the oldest files to make room for new files as they are uploaded. Also i would only like to delete a few of the old files to make room for new as they are uploaded to the server.

I would like to know if it is possible to have an automated script to run in the background and check every X number of minutes and maybe make it so I can have it take care of multiple directories...

Right now i am logging in and taking care of it by hand, but it is tedious and very time consuming. So any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 1):

I would use cron (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to execute a bash script that you can write yourself.

You can find information about a bash script that is similar to your needs here: https://superuser.com/questions/375011/bash-script-to-delete-old-files-older-than-x-days-with-subdirectories and if you need help using `cron` or `find` just open up your terminal and type `man cron` or `man find`

Comment: that is helpful, but i am trying to have a script to check for directories that are past a certain size then delete the oldest files first to make room for new....